# API Call with parameters

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I would like to contact my Api Laravel to extract data from the database.
On the Laravel side, I have functions that are SQL queries with parameters to my function.
If possible I would like to send a Post call to Laravel to specify which data I want and how can I retrieve them to display them on a component?
My controller returns a JSON array.

Thank you in advance.

My controller :

```
// R�cup�ration de l'indicateur sur les nouveaux baux MLS
$newBauxEnCours = $productRepository->getProducts($request);
    


return response()->json([$newBauxEnCours]);
```

My Scoped :

```
public function getProducts($request)
{
    $status = $request->get('status');
    $date = $request->get('date');
    $typeTransac = $request->get('typeTransac');

   if (!$date) {
    $arrayIdProducts = ProductCritereCache::select('products_id')
    ->whereIn('121', $status)
    ->whereIn('products_date_added', '>', $date)
    ->whereIn('28', $typeTransac)
    ->whereIn('products_id', $productsId)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('products_id')
    ->implode(',');
    return $arrayIdProducts;
}
```

}

The repo :

```
    public function getProducts($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

change API to POST and use [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#available-validation-rules). validate will automatically return exception if the data is not correct

```
public function getProducts(Request $request){
    $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'param1'    => ['required', 'int'],
        'param2'    => ['required', 'string'],
        etc...
    ]);
    
    if ($validate->fails()) return $validate->messages();
```

Comment: @HCP I was glad to help =)
If the answer helped you, mark it right to help future users.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You want me to close the post?
The answer helps me because I didn't put a validation but it's not the answer I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

use Request class

```
    public function_name(Request $request,YourReposatry $YourReposatry)
    {
     return $YourReposatry->functionName($request);
    }
```

and in your repo :

```
    public function functionName($request){
     $pram_1=$request->name_of_param_1;
     }
```

Comment: I just saw the Request method but I can't use it.
I just modified my post.
What do you think about it?

Ps: I don't know how to test my code because I need a token ^^